# C++ - cast defined string to wide string (L prefix)

Tags: c++, widechar

Lets say I have defined string :

```
#define MY_STRING "This is my string"
```

However some functions require my string to have an L prefix (extended format).

Of course I could make another macro

```
 #define MY_STRING_LONG L"This is my string"
```

But that would require me to change each time two strings.
Is it possible to "cast" it as wide while using non-wide macro?